# How can I build an application for iPhone OS 3.1.2 using the current Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I have an iPhone running the 3.1.2 firmware and would like to build applications for it.  However, I can't find Xcode 3.2.1 with the iPhone OS 3.1.2 SDK at Apple's developer site.

How can I build an application using the current SDK and Xcode versions that will run on this older OS version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the current tools and SDK. Set the "Base SDK" build setting to "Latest iOS" and set the "iOS Deployment Target" to whatever version you want to target, such as iOS 3.1.2.

The only gotcha here is that the compiler won't warn you if you use something from the SDK that was introduced after iOS 3.1.2, and if you do your app will likely crash. So, you'll want to check the docs for each method you use that you don't already know for certain is available in 3.1.2, and you should test your app thoroughly.

Comment: how can i get iOS 3.1.2? this is a big problem for me.

Comment: You don't NEED the iOS 3.1.2 SDK -- support for 3.1.2 is built into the current SDK. If you're trying to get the actual OS to install on your device, you're probably out of luck unless you can find it somewhere on the net.

Comment: I don't NEED the iOS 3.1.2 SDK? my current SDK is 4.0, I created Hello application, and 'Build and Run', it crashed at my phone.

Comment: @nonocast - Did you set the Deployment Target of that application to 3.1 like Caleb suggested?  You need to do this for your application to run on your device.  Also, does the "Hello World" application use anything that is 4.0-specific?  If so, alter the code to be compatible with 3.x.

Comment: I has set Deployment Target to 3.1.2, maybe the problem is the phone, when I upgrade my iphone to 4.1, everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some unmentioned reason you need the older version, you can use the latest Xcode and just target the build for the old iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a member of the Apple Developer Program (which you need to be in order to download any version of the Xcode and iOS SDK), you can download Xcode 3.2.6 w/ iOS SDK from the main  4.3 from the iOS Dev Center home page. Under the section for Xcode 4, there's a small line saying "Looking for Xcode 3? Download", which takes you to [this download page](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792).

Of course, that still requires you to develop using the 4.3 SDK, so you have to be carefull when targeting 3.1.2 devices.

Comment: now I installed xcode 3.2.6 with iOS4 which downloaded from that page, but the code doesn't work at my phone.

Comment: This is probably because you build the code with a deployment target version > 3.1.2. In any case, I don't think people here will be able to help you without you giving more information on what the exact error is. I would suggest you post this as a separate question though.

Answer (score -2):

You can purchase Xcode using the Mac-App-Store or by subscribing to the iPhone Developer Program ($99 per year).

Get the latest one (XCode with iOS SDK 4.3) and select 3.1.2 for the deployment iOS Version (under build-settings).

Comment: Not necessary to pay for the developer program. You can download Xcode for free by simply registering. http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/